# removing duplicate options in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model in which the user has one attribute named **division**. Many users can have same division. 
So when I'm using,

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :div, User.all, :division, :division) %>
```

it is giving duplicate values for division field. I know it is obvious but I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :div, User.pluck(:division).uniq) %>
```

Comment: error: undefined method pluck...<br/>
my project is in rails 3.1

Comment: it's a Rails 3.2 method only... Try user Person.distinct(:division) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `options_for_select` ([options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)) helper and fill it with your array of uniq `divisions` from `User` model.